# Set list next to None

Tags: python, linked-list

When I try to make the `next` attribute of a node, `p`, of a linked list point to `None`, I use `p.next = None`. But what if I want to make the node corresponding to `p.next` to `None`?

An example would be when try to rotate a linked list, which ends with a node's `next` equal to `None`, I want to make the new list's last element's `next` point to `None` but I think I keep deleting the element that it pointed to.

Here's my code for rotating the list by `k` positions. If you want to see the full description of the problem see [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-list/)

```
def rotate(head, k):
'''
head is pointer to the head, k is the number of positions to rotate
'''
if not head or k == 0:
    return head

p = head
d = head
counter = 1

while p.next != None:
    counter += 1
    p = p.next

out = ListNode(0)

if k % counter == 0:
    return head
if counter < k:
    counter = counter % k

for _ in range(counter):
    p.next = d
    d = d.next
    p = p.next

out = p
d.next.next = None

return out
```

Comment: This is a code snippet, could you post your full code?

Comment: Actually, a [mcve] may be better @Laurent

Comment: Added the function header, which is used to read the pointer, head, and the number of positions to rotate, k.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to take the last `k` values and append them to the front.

`p.next` is the next node. In general when we want to change `p`'s `next` we need to grab `temp = p.next p.next = newNode` and then we can continue.

In this case though, I'd find the length of the list, set `tail.next = head`, subtract `k` (accounting for wraparound), then walk forward till `N-k`, and set that node's `p.next = None`

Something like:

```
p, len, prev = head, 0, None
while p:
  prev = p
  p = p.next
  len += 1
# prev is tail, set it's next to head
prev.next = head
# find the node to detach
p = head
for i in xrange(len):
  p = p.next
p.next = None
```

You'll need to figure out corner cases